# Will autogrowth overcome SQL Server Express database size limit?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I've hit the 4gb limit in my database and I need a bit of breathing space before upgrading it to a SQL Server 2008 database and I just wondered if increasing auto growth would give me more space inside the database beyond the 4GB limit that SQL Server 2005 Express imposes.

I know the pitfalls of Auto Growth with regards to performance as data will be fragmented across the disk and thus make querying it slower but is there an advantage in granting it say 50/100mb of room for auto growth? Whilst the migration process is planned out or an alternative is sought.

Disk space is not an issue and it would only be a temporary measure anyway.

Comment: You can't grow beyond the limit.

Comment: @dean why does the eventviwer logs tell me that is an option then?

Comment: You can set autogrowth, but it wont grow the database file beyond the 4 GB limit (log file size doesn't count). See here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345154%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: Even if this *was* possible, I'd assume it would be a violation of the license (but I'm not a lawyer)

Comment: MS made sure you cannot violate the license this time :)

Comment: I wasn't aware it was a licensing issue until now, I'll just to have to clear out some space in the database in the meantime I know there is some redundant log data in there I can clear out, like I say it will need migrating eventually to 2008 R2 that way i'll have 10gb of space

Answer (score 2):

No. Express Edition will not grow, nor attach or restore, a database over its size limit, no matter what the errorlog viewer tells you. Not even temporarily.

But you have an easy solution: [SQL Server 2008R2 Express Edition](http://rusanu.com/2010/04/28/sql-server-2008-r2-express-database-size-limit-10gb/) has raised the limit to 10GB.

Answer (score 1):

No it won't. The SQL Server Express edition is for creating Database-oriented applications without the need to purchase an official SQL Server licenses. However, you cannot use it in an production environment for more reasons other than just file size limit.

Answer (score 0):

No, once you've reached 10'240 MB (10*1024MB) , you're out of luck 
(technically not exactly 10GiB).